# Adjective to refer to someone who has high awareness of their environment

Tags: word-choice

How would you qualify someone who notices a lot of things in their environment (e.g., small changes in people's appearance, object moved from one place to another...).

I would like to say

> You're _____________.

Would you say a ***good observer, observant***? That just does not sound right to me.

Comment: Spot on. 'observer' serves everything you want to say. You may also call the person ***sharp-eyed***.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing someone with OCD

Comment: @VarunKN not really, more like someone who would notice that you have new glasses, or a new watch (etc.) and let you know that they noticed it. I'd like to reply ironically, you're a good ...

Comment: @VarunKN a *big* no to OCD! :)

Comment: @MaulikV It means both *able to perceive* and *familiar with*.

Comment: haha, I wasn't suggesting an answer...I was just saying it sounds like OCD.

Comment: @MaulikV I like sharp-eyed, I think it would be great used ironically

Comment: Yeah! I use that over *observer*, personally!

Comment: @MaulikV by the way would I reply back `you're sharp-eyed` or `you have really sharp eyes`? Please don't ask me to create a new thread for that :)

Comment: You ***have*** sharp eyes - in that case.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning here before you start using the words. Say -1) You *have sharp eyes* **on** any environmental change happening. 2) You are a *keen observer* **of** the environmental changes around us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it. You could use a few adjectives to *"observer"* to make it sound better. Maybe words like *'Keen'* or '*careful'* or *'sharp'* or *'intense'*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a **good observer** is natural and common in your context.

In addition, as a native speaker, I would not use *[sharp-eyed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sharp-eyed)* in this context. Although dictionaries say it means *observant*, it doesn't fit well here.

In addition, such a person is (highly) [attuned](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/attuned) to his or her environment.

attuned -
1 able to perceive; sensitive (to)   ⇒  ■ He seemed unusually attuned to people's feelings.,   ⇒  ■ I have become attuned to Carlisle's industrial past.

2 accustomed (to)   ⇒  ■ Their ears were still attuned to the sounds of the London suburb. -

Comment: I think attuned is more for getting 'familiar with' rather than noticing/observing. The person is a keen observer who notices even small changes according to OP

Comment: thanks, but maybe I wasn't clear enough in my description. I'm not talking about some kind of mentalist or someone with high emotional intelligence. I'm talking about people who notice physical changes in their environment (other people, objects)...

Comment: Antoine and @MaulikV A person highly attuned to his environment will notice changes in his environment.